# How to test for convergence (smoothness of Pareto front) in DEAP

Tags: optimization, python

In the DEAP algorithms ([see documentation here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html)), I notice that we need to specify the the number of generations (NGEN). I was advised that convergence has been achieved if the Pareto curve is smooth. How can I monitor for convergence in DEAP?

Update:
It is possible to monitor for convergence by specifying a "smoothness" value in the stats. However, I'm still confused about how to define "smoothness". For example, consider the [Knapsack problem specified here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_knapsack.html). How do we monitor for smoothness in this example?